# I have a regex for only numbers allowed, but need one for floating 0's also

Tags: regex

I have a regex for to check if an input field has only numbers in it:

```
if (paymentAmount.match(/[^0-9\.,]/g)) ... show error
```

I need to also check for if there are any 0's before the value also. For example, `0001.23` should throw an error, but 1.23 should be ok.

Is there a way to add this to the current regex check?

Comment: Please add the language you are using. It may make a difference in how the question is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
if (paymentAmount.match(/^(?!([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d\d?)?$)/)) ...
```

This will also detect input with two decimal points, and numbers with more than 2 decimals.

Here are some tests:

```js
function numCheck(paymentAmount) {
 console.log(paymentAmount, 
               (paymentAmount.match(/^(?!([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d\d?)?$)/)) 
                   ? ' error' : ' ok');
}

numCheck("1.0");
numCheck("1.0.0");
numCheck("01.0");
numCheck("1");
numCheck("10.09");
numCheck("10.");
numCheck(".01");
numCheck("10.0901");
```

However, it is more straightforward to do a positive test, i.e. a test confirming that the format is correct. You can always negate the result with `!`:

```
if (!paymentAmount.match(/^([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d\d?)?$/)) ...
```

Comment: Can you add this kind of check to the above regex. numCheck("10.0901"); so only 2 numbers can be after the decimal.

Comment: Thank you for doing that. :)

Comment: Would it be possible to allow only one floating 0 before the value. Right now its checking for all floating 0's which I asked for but thinking I might have a case where it would be correct to have 01.00. but not 001.00

Comment: Sure, then add `0?` before `[1-9]`. But if you have more questions like that, just don't hesitate to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks that would work but not if you had 020.00. I guess I can open another ticket for this.

Comment: I don't understand. If you add `0?` before  `[1-9]` then the value of `020.00` will be considered correct, just like `010.00`. Maybe I misunderstood your new requirements? But yes, opening a new question is certainly the way ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if ( /[^0-9.,]/g.test(paymentAmount) || /^0+[1-9.]/.test(paymentAmount) ) {
   // ... show error
}
```

`^0+[1-9]` will match 1 or more zeroes before any digit `[1-9]` or a decimal point.